# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' when reading from a JSON file using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to read from a JSON file, but I get this error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

```
import pandas as pd


osp_json_path = 'Data/syllabi.sample.json'

df_osp_data = pd.read_json(osp_json_path)


print(df.head())
```

Here is some of the sample of the JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 17308718202881,
    "syllabus_probability": 0.6546372771263123,
    "date": {
      "year": 2016,
      "term": null
    },
    "field": {
      "code": "11",
      "name": "Computer Science",
      "label_precision": 0.7397769689559937,
      "label_recall": 0.8223140239715576,
      "label_f1": 0.7788649797439575
    },
    "institution": {
      "id": 3994319585322,
      "grid_id": "grid.7112.5",
      "wikidata_id": "Q1783765",
      "unitid": null,
      "name": "Mendel University Brno",
      "url": "http:\/\/mendelu.cz\/en\/",
      "lat": 49.210208892822266
    },
    "extracted_metadata": {
      "code": {
        "text": "VT1",
        "clean_text": "VT1",
        "mean_p": 0.9811509251594543
      },
      "title": {
        "text": "Computer Technology I",
        "clean_text": "Computer Technology I",
        "mean_p": 0.9993407726287842
      },
      "date": {
        "text": "SS 2016\/2017",
        "clean_text": "SS 2016\/2017",
        "mean_p": 0.9996379613876343
      },
      "description": [
        {
          "text": "The aim of this course is to introduce students into the subject of computer science and data processing and to explain basic principles of computer operations. The part relating to operating systems is centered on operations with computer files and processes in systems Windows and Unix\/Linux.",
          "clean_text": "The aim of this course is to introduce students into the subject of computer science and data processing and to explain basic principles of computer operations. The part relating to operating systems is centered on operations with computer files and processes in systems Windows and Unix\/Linux.",
          "mean_p": 0.9988000392913818
        }
      ]
    },
    "text_md5": "18443cb0375d7ba646c5ac203aac7380",
    "mime_type": "text\/xml",
    "anonymized_text": "Department of Informatics (FBE) Time allowance:  full-time, period A\u00a02\/0, period B 2\/2  (hours of lectures per week \/ hours of seminars per week) Prerequisites for registration:  not  Computer Technology and Algorithms I  and not  Final Bachelor Exam Type of study:  consulting Form of teaching:  lecture, seminar Mode of completion and credits:  Fulfillment of requirements (2 credits) \u00a0 Course objective:  The aim of this course is to introduce students into the subject of computer science and data processing and to explain basic principles of computer operations. The part relating to operating systems is centered on operations with computer files and processes in systems Windows and Unix\/Linux. \u00a0 Course content:  1. Introduction to computer science  (allowance 2\/0) \u00a0 a. Basic concepts"
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this TypeError? Also, not all fields are necessary, only "id" and "anonymized_text" are going to be used, so filtering some keys is also a possibility.

Comment: It seems like some of the JSON is malformed, and you have a map/dict as the key to another dict. I don't see that here though.

Comment: ^ yes, malformed JSON, otherwise the code works. Remove [ at beginning of file